# Stripe Laravel : Api key must be a string

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

my app is builded with laravel 8, laravel Mix 6.0.39 , vue js 2.6 and vuex 3.0.1 
I used cashier for payment module
so in payment component I have this code to initialise payment method:

```
 let apikey = process.env.MIX_STRIPE_KEY
 this.stripe = await loadStripe(apikey)
 const elements = this.stripe.elements()
...
```

.env file :

```
STRIPE_SECRET=sk_test_.....

STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET =we_....

MIX_STRIPE_KEY ="${STRIPE_KEY}"
```

but i have the following error in mounted payment method :
`IntegrationError: Missing value for Stripe(): apiKey should be a string.`

I try to show the variable `process.env.MIX_STRIPE_KEY` in log and I have `undefined`, But it is initialised in `.env`file 
Have you an idea to fix this problem ?

Comment: wait how are you using server side javascript code like `process.env`? You mentioned Laravel 8 (php; serverside) and Vue 2.6 (js; clientside)

Comment: [https://coderedirect.com/questions/26662/retrieve-config-and-env-variable-in-vue-component] @Flame take a look

Comment: What is `"${STRIPE_KEY}"` exactly? Looks like some kind of variable?

Answer (score 1):

You use the `STRIPE_KEY` value for your `MIX_STRIPE_KEY`, but have you actually defined the value for `STRIPE_KEY` in your `.env`?
I see the `STRIPE_SECRET`, and the `WEBHOOK_SECRET`, you also need the `STRIPE_PUBLIC` (or `STRIPE_KEY` in your case) key. You'll find the public key in your Stripe Dashboard, just where you found the secret.

So it should look like:

```
STRIPE_SECRET=sk_test_.....
STRIPE_KEY=pk_test_.....
STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET=we_....
MIX_STRIPE_KEY="${STRIPE_KEY}"
```

Also, don't forget to restart your local server after changing the `.env`